# File delete is not working via ant script

Tags: ant

I have written an Ant script in which there is some block of codes which create a temp file and apply ant filters to that temp file and generate new one.

following is the code:

```
<copy tofile="${file.report.name}.html" file="${file.report.name}-temp.html">
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter>
                    <replaceregex pattern="\[(echo|script|apply|copy)\]" replace="" />
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
            <filterchain>
                <linecontains negate="true">
                    <contains value="Copying"/>
                </linecontains>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>

        <antcall target="final.cleanup"/>
```

and then i call a target for deletion of generated temp file. but its giving me some error saying that script is unable to delete the respected file.

Following code block i am using for deletion of temp file:

```
<target name="final.cleanup">
        <delete file="reports/report-temp.html"/>
    </target>
```

What went wrong? Is this file is being used in some process that's why it giving me the error !

Comment: Provide the error stack trace.

Comment: Provide all the error messages. Failing to delete a file is usually because of some other one is using the file. Try `deleteonexit="true"` of the `delete` task to see if the file can be deleted via a shutdown hook.

Comment: I added deleteonexit="true" and it working fine...
Thanks a lot .........

Comment: OK.. there should be something holding the file during the build. Can you still post the error message here so that we can know more about your problem?

Comment: When i remove deleteonexit="true" it not working with following error:

BUILD FAILED
D:\Web\build.xml:182: Unable to delete file
D:\Web\reports\report-temp.html